# Remapping Alt key to Ctrl key in AutoHotKey causes both keys to be pressed

Tags: macos, windows-7, keyboard, macros, autohotkey

So, just like the title says, whenever I remap my LAlt key to LCtrl (or LCtrl to LAlt) they both get pressed when either key is used, and this causes a variety of issues.

The main reason I need these keys to be swapped is for use with a Mac keyboard on a Windows 7 computer. Honestly, though, it is only the beginning of my problem. *I would actually like the LAlt key to be the LCtrl key, the LWin key to be the LAlt key, and the LCtrl key to be the LWin key so it appropriately emulates the Mac keyboard for personal use within **Pro Tools 10**.* When I attempt this 3-way-swap, LCtrl and LWin function properly (as LWin and LAlt respectively), however, the LAlt key continues to press both LCtrl and LAlt anyways.

My code looks like this:

```
#IfWinActive
LAlt::LCtrl
LWin::LAlt
LCtrl::LWin
Return
```

I am fairly new to AHK, but this shouldn't be overly complicated, right? It's pretty short and sweet, and I'm not even worried about the Alt+Tab ordeal; I just need to figure out the issue so these three buttons can be swapped correctly. If anyone has any clue as to why this might be happening, I would be profoundly grateful. Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: You have a duplicated hotkey, that code doesn't compile.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, and pointing out my mistake. I actually made a typo when typing the code on here (I should have just copy-pasted, but the code was small enough anyways). I edited the OP to reflect the code that I actually have.

Comment: This might be a limitation of Autohotkey.

Comment: I think you might have to create hotkeys for every key combination you want to remap using `!`, `^`, `#` instead of `LAlt`,`LCtrl`, `LWin`.

Comment: So, with the code:                                                                      #IfWinActive
!::^
#::!
^::#                                                                                                           I still get the Ctrl+Alt issue when I press Alt -- PLUS -- the windows key and the Ctrl remain unchanged somehow

Comment: I don't think that will work. I think you will need to create hotkeys for every combination you actually need.

Comment: Are there any examples of how I should be doing it?

Comment: I think this is an interesting case and you should post this on Autohotkey forums and support.

Comment: Okay, will do! Thank you for the help so far.

Comment: Please leave a link to those posts here if you can. I'm also interested in this.

Comment: Apparently, AHK's forum is not accepting new user registration, what's up with that?

Comment: Try https://autohotkey.com/boards/  
The old forum is just an archive now.

Answer (score 1):

I think your hotkeys are probably triggering each other.

When you hit LALT, it sends LCTRL, which triggers LALT...
When you have a hotkey whose output matches the input of another hotkey, prefix your hotkeys with `$` to stop them triggering each other:

```
$LAlt::LCtrl
$LWin::LAlt
$LCtrl::LWin
```

Also, I don't think your `#IfWinActive` is doing anything, since it has no `WinTitle` param, plus the `return` at the end is not how you end an `#IfWinActive` block, you start it with `#IfWinActive <WinTitle>` and end it with `#IfWinActive`